# File upload in ASP.NET MVC3 via Ajax not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, jquery

I'd already submitted a file in mvc3 normally.Now I'm required to do the same with Ajax.So I used this jquery plugin:  http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit

View code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            url: "/Home/TakeFile",
            dataType: "json",
            success: showResponse
        };


        $("#File").submit(function () {
            alert("submit");
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
            return false;
        });
    });


    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        alert("showResponse");
        alert(responseText.fileName);
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("TakeFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "File", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Click to submit" id="button" />
}
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TakeFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            return Json(new { fileName=file.FileName});
        }
```

The file parameter in my 'TakeFile' method is always null.Can't seem to get it working.Also, can we do it using 'Ajax.BeginForm()' helper??

Comment: The file just doesn't upload...otherwise it goes to the appropriate method in the controller, also I can send a response back which is received correctly in 'showResponse()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **name** attribute of an `<input>` html element inside a `<form>` is used to reference the form data after a form is submitted.

Note: Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

As the action method  `public ActionResult TakeFile(HttpPostedFileBase file){..}` has a parameter name 'file', in the view, file input element should have a `name='file'` attribute. Updated code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TakeFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "File", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Click to submit" id="button" />
}
```

Comment: Thanks..that was the only flaw..missed out on the name attribute of the input type!!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you are not allowed to upload a file via ajax... a full postback is required to post the file.

You need a flash solution or something like that in order to make it happend.
Use [UPLOADIFY](http://www.uploadify.com/) for example...

[See this blog post to make it work](http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Upload-Files-In-RAZOR-With-jQuery-Uploadify-Plugin.aspx)

Comment: Yup.Even I'm using a plugin, a different one though

Comment: What are you using? I didn't found the best solution for my case.

Comment: This plugin worked well: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit
Still have to use it in my actual project and see though.This code was a sample.

Answer (score 0):

try using follows

```
<input type="file" id="file" name = "attachment"/>
```

inside your controller add the following code to grab the file object

```
var file = Request.Files["attachment"];
```

Comment: That's because you are sending an Ajax request as well. stop the Ajax request and try again, that should work because I have used this code before

Answer (score 0):

The `dataType:json` in your options seems strange when uploading a file, did you try removing it?

Also try using the `Name` attribute with the input type

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
```

Comment: Actually, the 'datatype' tells you the type of response you get from the server, not what request is going to it.

Comment: Yes that's true. I just see that the id of the form is the same as the id of the input type..

Comment: Oh..yeah...will change any one id and see